# how to get the source code based on url using java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, cross-browser, xmlhttprequest

i wrote some code to get the html source code but it is working only IE8,but not working on mozila and chrome , what is the problem , please give me suggestion.
my code

```
<script>

        function processStateChange() {
            statusDiv = document.getElementById("stats");
            if (req.readyState == 0) { statusDiv.innerHTML = "UNINITIALIZED"; }
            if (req.readyState == 1) { statusDiv.innerHTML = "LOADING"; }
            if (req.readyState == 2) { statusDiv.innerHTML = "LOADED"; }
            if (req.readyState == 3) { statusDiv.innerHTML = "INTERACTIVE"; }
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                statusDiv.innerHTML = "COMPLETE";
                statusDiv.innerHTML = req.responseText;
            }
        }
        function GetXmlHttpObject() {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                return new XMLHttpRequest();
            } if (window.ActiveXObject) {  // code for IE6, IE5 
                return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } return null;
        }
        //req = new XMLHttpRequest("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");     
        req = GetXmlHttpObject();
        debugger;
        if (req) {
            req.onreadystatechange = processStateChange;
            req.open("GET", "http://whatismyipaddress.com/", true);            
            req.send();
        }

    </script>
```

i checked to debug the code IE was completely working the loop(req.readystate==4 to finally get the response text) but mozila or chromes are only working loop(req.readystate==2 after abort the loop), what is the problem, please give me some suggestion, using jquery or java script to solve the problem

Thank u
hemanth

Comment: any reason you are not using a library like `jQuery` ?

Comment: @MihaiIorga Not really relevant

Comment: @hmk You've checked the js console? no error there?

Comment: Trying it in jsfiddle, I get this: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://whatismyipaddress.com/. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: pls give me some example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction you cannot send cross domain AJAX calls. The reason this works in IE is probably that you are using some old dinosaurish version of IE that has some bugs and allows such an AJAX request. But no modern browser will ever allow you to do that.

You can send AJAX requests only to the domain from which originated the page containing the javascript code sending the AJAX request.

There are some workarounds depending on the level of control you have over the remote domain. In your case I guess that you have no control over `http://whatismyipaddress.com/`. So your only option is to write a server side script on your domain that will serve as a bridge between your domain and the remote domain and then send the AJAX request to your script:

```
req.open("GET", "/myscript", true);
```

Comment: there is no way to get the data using jquery or java script, please give me some example, i have to get the city name in http://whatismyipaddress.com/,

Comment: Sorry, this is not possible with javascript. As I already explained in my answer the same origin policy restriction that's built into the browsers simply won't allow you to. The way to achieve that is to write a server side script (PHP, ASP.NET, Java, ...) that will query the remote service and then use javascript to send an AJAX request to your script.